# Reportico : YII2 ADONewConnection: Unable to load database drive

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, reportico

I've installed Reportico For yii2 when i try to go to Administration   page

Firstly : i got error that says

> Projects area does not exist - cannot write project

I googled this problem then i found a solution  : Rename file config.template to config.php  in directory

> vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\projects\admin

i did it and added the code `define('SW_ADMIN_PASSWORD','xxxx')`

it works but the problem shown after that

> Missing file: C:\xampp\htdocs\Atom\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb/drivers/adodb-n/a.inc.php
>   ADONewConnection: Unable to load database driver ''

and

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Atom\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb\adodb.inc.php Line 4080 - include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Atom\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb/drivers/adodb-n/a.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

and

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Atom\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb\adodb.inc.php Line 4080 - include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Atom\vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico_adodb/drivers/adodb-n/a.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ..

move the config.php back to config.template

copy the file adminconfig.template to config.php instead and set the password as suggested and then try

Really , you should put everything back, remove the config.php , then repoint at index.php?r=reportico or index.php/reportico.

If you remove the config.php and restart, are you seeing the screens shown here?

http://reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/installation

Comment: Thank you .. it works fine ..  but there is a little problem .. i created a Project (atom)  and i create a report (Receipts) when i try to embed link i used `http://localhost/Atom/backend/web/index.php?r=reportico/mode/prepare?project=atom&report=Receipts.xml`  i got  `Page not found.`

Comment: Perhaps you need an ampersand instead  ..  http://localhost/Atom/backend/web/index.php?r=reportico/mode‌​/prepare&project=ato‌​m&report=Receipts.xm‌​l

Comment: i don't get it . can you explain it !

Comment: Ok you have "prepare?project" .. you need "prepare&project" .... so if you look at the bottom of  [http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-links](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-links) you will see link to what you want   ...  if you want to actually embed reportico within a page you would use the examples on [http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-reports](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-reports)

Comment: there is anther issue can i ask you here or new Question ?

Comment: i used this one http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-reports-prepare-bare and i put it in PHP File  Atom\backend\views\report\receipts.php  when i try to open it by a button the page i got the report title and password no thing else .